# Map Property returning NotFoundException using Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a class that has properties throwing exceptions if not populated. I would like to map this class to a DTO class using Automapper. How can I achieve this?

If nos.Price throws an exception, I need to map it to 0.

```
        CreateMap<NewOrderSingle, Order>()
            .ForMember(o => o.Price, map => map.MapFrom(nos => nos.Price != null ? nos.Price.getValue() : 0))
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: can you include the classes that are source and destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            CreateMap<NewOrderSingle, Order>()               
            .ForMember((src => src.Price), opt => opt.Ignore()).
                BeforeMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dest.Price = src.Price.getValue();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dest.Price = 0;
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
CreateMap<NewOrderSingle, Order>()
    .ForMember(o=>o.Price, options => options.MapFrom((src,dst)=>
    {
        try
        {
            return src.Price;
        }
        catch   
        {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```